# I've made something hidden in css, i can't make it visible now when I click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new to all of this and still learning :s

So in my css, i've done this...

```
.example {
 display: none;
}
```

I have a button which when i click makes other divs invis as well as trying to make it so that .example will be visible.

I am using an onClick function...this is where I set the other div invis...

```
document.getElementById("thisdiv").style.display = "none";
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make the other div visible now?

Comment: Please include all of your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript that is used, so that we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("thisdiv").style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the display to "block" or use jQuery's show() function

```
$('.example').show();
```

Comment: @BlueDeath yeah, makes sense. Changed.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this:

```
$("#show").click(function(){
    $(".example").css({"display":"block"});     
});

$("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".example").css({"display":"none"});           
});
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/981oek8z/

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted much of your source code I have created a little demo to show you how to set the display for all elements using a class.

**This doesn't require jQuery**

```js
function showclass(){
 document.getElementById('thisdiv').style.display="none";
 var examples=document.getElementsByClassName('example');
 for(var i=0; i<examples.length; i++){
  examples[i].style.display="block";
 }
}
```

```css
.example{display:none;}
```

```html
 <button onclick="showclass()">Show example Class</button>
<div id="thisdiv"> This Div will disappear </div> 
<div class="example">Example Div One</div>
<div class="example">Example Div Two</div>
<div class="example">Example Div Three</div>
```

I hope this helps, happy coding! :)